# Возможно ли восстановить файл после прохода через эту функцию?

Tags: python, linux, безопасность, резервное-копирование, recovery

Я написал скрипт, по типу shred в линуксе, его центральная часть в этих строчках.

```
def shred():

  with open(file, 'r+') as f:
            size = os.path.getsize(file)
            null_str = '0' * size
            for i in range(1, cycles + 1): # For progress_bar
                f.seek(0)
                f.write(null_str)
```

Описание кода (для тех, кто в безопасность, но не в питон):

1) Получаем размер файла в байтах

2) Создаем переменную длиной в файл, состоящую из нулей.

3) цикл:

4) Переходим в начало файла

5) Записываем созданную переменную в файл.

Возможно ли восстановить файл, достаточно ли это секьюрно ?

Comment: Наверняка возможны случаи, когда новы файл запишется совсем в не то место на диске, где был старый. Восстановить старый в такой ситуации совсем не проблема.

Comment: Да, я думал об фрагментации. Именно поэтому в файл записывается ровно столько данных, сколько было, что бы избежать ее.

Comment: @ДавидШико `Linux` использует файловую систему `ext4`, а в ней, насколько я знаю, фрагментация отсутствует. Также утилита `shred` в Линуксе делает перезапись файла по умолчанию 3 раза и перезаписывает не символами нулей, а рандомными данными (`/dev/urandom`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файловая система - это абстракция над физическим устройством. Казалось, бы ставим через `seek` указаталь в какое-то место файла и перезаписываем. Но не все так просто.

Тезисы такие:

- нули не подходят, нужно использовать случайные данные, причем в несколько проходов. Иначе можно восстановить через [Магнитно-силовую микроскопию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_force_microscope)
- существует "Копирование при записи" (Copy-on-write), поэтому физического перезатирания не происходит, нужно это обойти
- могут остаться данные на одном из зеркал RAID массива
- фрагментация: файл начинается в одной части диска, заканчивается в другой, и такая "последовательная" перезапись не затрет данные
- система антифрагментации может оставить копии данных в других частях носителя
- SSD диски управляют адресным пространством не так, как HDD. В частности, есть функция выравнивания износа накопителя
- есть файловые системы с версионированием типа [ZFS](https://habr.com/ru/post/424651/):

  > Снимки могут быть смонтированы в формате read-only для восстановления старой версии файла
- лучше не "сжигать" данные, а шифровать еще до попадания на диск

[Вот хороший ответ с enSO](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/15758), большая часть взята оттуда.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос: возможно.

Comment: Добавлю что ввод-вывод в питоне буферизован и без f.flush() все усилия умноженны на `'0'`)

Comment: @eri, ну не совсем. ОС при закрытии файлового дескриптора может сама сделать flush.

Comment: при закрытии естественно, но я про то что несколько проходов делается без закрытия и без сброса